# Redhat JBOSS EAP 7.3.8 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, logging, jboss, redhat, logback

I am trying to integrate logback to maven project and deploying the application in RedHat JBoss eap 7.3.8 application server.

I am getting following error in JBoss console when starting.
Jboss console.

> 18:33:09,411 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) SLF4J: Failed to
> load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 18:33:09,411 ERROR
> [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation
> (NOP) logger implementation 18:33:09,411 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service
> thread 1-4) SLF4J: See
> http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details. 18:33:13,740 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88)
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (SessionManager).
> 18:33:13,741 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88)
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22</version>
        </dependency>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml in project WEB-INF directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

logback.xml in project resources directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <contextName>test</contextName>
    <!--configPath should be passed as a VM argument on application start-->
    <!--<property file="application.yml" />-->
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="/data/logs/test/server.log"/>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/data/logs/test/server.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/data/logs/test/server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 5 days worth of history kept at 1GB total size -->
            <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %-5level %contextName [%thread] %X{eventType} %5p ${hostName}  %logger{40}: %msg%n</                                                                                                                                 pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <!-- Minimum logging level to be presented in the console logs-->
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %-5level %contextName [%thread] %X{eventType} %5p ${hostName} %logger{40}: %msg%n</pattern>                                                                                                                                 attern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="jacatlas.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="jacatlas.web" level="DEBUG"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Is this a WAR or an EAR deployment?

Comment: @James R. Perkins this is war deployment.

Comment: Have you checked your WAR to ensure logback is in it? It seems strange that it can't find the binder.

Comment: I checked WAR is having logback in it and it is already there.this is very strange and cant identify the rootcause.

Comment: Maybe you need the `log4j-over-slf4j` dependency too. I'm only guessing because of the log4j error in the log message.